Which relay is required for this time switch?
I'm a high school student working on a time switch project and could use some advice. Should I use a 4-pin or 5-pin relay for this circuit? I noticed that 4-pin relays are hard to find on Amazon. Also, would a 9V relay work instead of a 6V one? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You can read more about the project on page 11(project 3) of this pdf. https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/sciencelaboratorymanuals/classXII/physics/lelm314.pdf

The circuit shows the type of relay: reed. Search this version, it is easy to find 4 pins units with coil 5 V (change also power supply). A 9 V relay will not work realibly with 6 V battery.

The majority of 4 pin relays will have normally open contacts; the 5th pin usually adds a normally closed contact, which is what your schematic seems to need.

The schematic specifies that the relay contacts should be normally closed (NC), which is not something you will find easily in a 4-pin design. The reason is that 4-pin relays use two pins for the coil, and the remaining 2 will usually be normally open (NO). The schematic mentions a "normally closed reed relay", the mechanics of which you can read about here, but I suspect these will be difficult to find.
Almost all relays with 5 pins will do what you require. Two pins for the coil as usual, but the three other pins will form a "double-throw switch", whose symbol looks like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On the left, the switch is in the "normal" position, and is un-pressed, or released. As you can see, there is a conductive path between COM and NC, but the connection between COM and NO is broken.
On the right, the switch has been pressed, or if this switch formed part of a relay, "activated". In this state the path between COM and NC has been broken, and instead COM is connected to NO.
Here's that very same switch depicted inside a relay symbol:

simulate this circuit
This is fairly self-explanatory, and you can read more about it in my most popular answer ever, for some reason. In the un-activated "normal" state (no coil current), COM is physically connected to NC, hence the name "normally closed". When current flows in the coil, a magnetic field is created which attracts the switch lever, and this causes the the COM-to-NC connection to break, and COM to be connected physically to NO instead.
You are not obliged to connect anything to the NO terminal at all, if you don't need it. Your own application requires only the COM and NC terminals to be used, so a 5-terminal relay would work perfectly well for you. As a bonus, if you wished to reverse the lamp's behaviour, to switch on when it used to be off and vice versa, simply use the COM and NO terminals instead.
You could even use a relay containing two independent switches, and use only one of them. Such a relay would be called "double-pole".
You second point regarding the relay's coil voltage isn't such good news. You must use a relay with a coil rated for the power supply you intend to use. If this circuit is to be powered from 6V, then you must use a relay with a 6V coil. If the supply is a 9V battery, then your relay must have a coil rated for 9V.
In this application, you might get away with using a 5V relay coil with a 6V supply, it's unlikely to fail, but it will get a little warmer than it should. There's a good chance that a 9V coil will fail to "activate" at all when supplied with only 6V. No engineer would ever recommend that you use a coil rated for a different voltage from the supply you intend to use, without somehow modifying the circuit to compensate in some way, but that's beyond the scope of this answer. Long story short, if you have a 6V supply, use a relay with a 6V-rated coil.
Lastly, the relay in your schematic specifies a reed relay with a coil resistance of 1kΩ resistance, or a "magnetic" relay with resistance 185Ω. I'm not sure what a "magnetic relay" is, but I assume it's the more common "boxed" type like the one pictured here (from Digikey's website):

The higher the resistance, the less current is required by the coil, and the less power will be consumed (wasted) by the relay. Obviously, then, higher resistance coils yield longer battery life. Using Ohm's law, you can find what current that coil would require at 6V:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{6V}{185\Omega} = 32mA $$
Digikey and Mouser have extensive ranges of relays. To get you going, here's a link to some 6V low current relays at Digikey. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to use the filters at the top of the page to find one whose coil needs only 32mA, or thereabouts.

A lot of relays have "Form C" contacts, meaning there is a common pin that switches back and forth between the normally open (NO) and normally closed (NC) contacts. There can also be multiple sets of these (poles) in the same relay. The designer simply uses whichever connections are needed and leaves the others unconnected.
A double-pole double-throw (DPDT) arrangement is very common:

Relays usually have a minimum switching voltage specified in the datasheet which is typically 20-40% under the rated coil voltage. I think it would be risky to drive a 9V coil from a 6V supply and expect reliable operation. However, it looks like you could change your supply to 9V if you changed your lamp 'L' to a 9V rating also.
